# How do I link dropdownlist value with querystring

Tags: c#, asp.net, csv

I have dropdownlist like this:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server"
    Height="20px" Width="1650px" AutoPostBack="True">
     <asp:ListItem>spy</asp:ListItem>
     <asp:ListItem>uk</asp:ListItem>
     <asp:ListItem>it</asp:ListItem>
     <asp:ListItem>us</asp:ListItem>
     <asp:ListItem>fr</asp:ListItem>
     <asp:ListItem>tr</asp:ListItem>
     <asp:ListItem>jp</asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
```

And have csv files(like spy-atma.csv) for data. And datalist show some data.

Here is code side:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{   
    var csv2 = DropDownList1.SelectedValue + "-atma" + ".csv";
    SqlDataSource2.SelectCommand = String.Format("SELECT * FROM [{0}]", csv2);
    DataList1.DataBind();

  }
```

I need to do querystring like this:

```
 atma.aspx?=spy
 atma.aspx?=uk
 ...
```

And binding dropdownlist selected value. When I click atma.aspx?=spy, dropdownlist default clicked value must be spy.

How can I do this?

Comment: If I understand you correctly - just set selected value on your dropdownlist tot he value of the query string (might need some string comparison). Also - you should look into fixing your SQL Injection vulnerability. It's open to attack the way you build your sql command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all your dropdown should be like:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server"
    Height="20px" Width="1650px" AutoPostBack="True">
     <asp:ListItem Text="spy" Value="spy"></asp:ListItem>
     <asp:ListItem Text="uk" Value="uk"></asp:ListItem>
     <asp:ListItem Text="it" Value="it"></asp:ListItem>
     <asp:ListItem Text="us" Value="us"></asp:ListItem>
     <asp:ListItem Text="fr" Value="fr"></asp:ListItem>
     <asp:ListItem Text="tr" Value="tr"></asp:ListItem>
     <asp:ListItem Text="jp" Value="jp"></asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
```

and you can get QueryString Value and set selected this way:

```
if(!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Request.QueryString["NameYouHaveSet"]))
    DropDownList1.SelectedValue = Request.QueryString["NameYouHaveSet"];
```

or use Index as it is on first index you can write:

```
NameValueCollection n = Request.QueryString;
if(!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(n.Get(0)))
        DropDownList1.SelectesValue = n.Get(0);
```

See [this example on this article](http://www.dotnetperls.com/querystring)

Comment: Thanks it's work. But I think it's selectedvalue. Thank you again.

Comment: you are welcome and yes it is ``SelectedValue`` it was spell mistake